# Как исправить ошибку при нажатии кнопки selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь сделать автоматизацию по прохождению тестов на сайте. Возникла проблема с нажатием последней кнопки, которая покажет результаты. Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при выводе кол-ва тэгов input в консоли, показывает, что всего не 21 tag_name < input >, а 19. Через xpath находить не вариант, потому что id с каждым разом меняется. Через CSSSelector тоже самое. Как пофиксить, чтобы при переходе на данную страницу, я мог нажать на кнопку завершения?
Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('mylink') # Перехожу по ссылке

start_button = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')[8] # Ищем кнопку для старта теста (скрин 2)
start_button.click() # Кликаем


end_test_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="mod_quiz_navblock"]/div/div/div[2]/a') # Ищем кнопку для завершения теста (скрин 3)
end_test_button.click() # Кликаем

pass_test_button = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')[9] # Ищем кнопку для сдачи теста (скрин 4)
pass_test_button.click() # Кликаем

finally_pass = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input') # Ищем все тэги input (Скрин 1)
print(len(finally_pass)) # Выводим длину, длина 19
```

```
output: 19
```

Скрин 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин 3:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин 4:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы не можете вместо этого добавить time.sleep(5) и в этом промежутке нажать на кнопку?

Comment: @VadSim Спасибо большое. Я думал, что от этого ничего не измениться, страница же загрузилась, поэтому не стал прописывать time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

Используйте поиск по селектору `button[type=submit]`. Или через XPath по тексту элемента.

Comment: Ответ уже дали в комментах